# How to properly save ManyToOne Entities?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

When I try to save my entity ("Chapter") with post I get this exception:

`org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of "domain.Book" (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (81)`

When I use `@JsonIgnore` on `@ManyToOne` field other data saves fine.
I think the problem is in the way I save "Chapter" but I have no idea how to change it to a proper way.

**JSON for POST:**

```
{
  "name": "testBookName",
  "chapters": [
    {
      "name": "testChapterName",
      "number": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "id": 99,
  "book": null,
  "number": 1,
  "name": "testChapterName",
  "pages": null
}
```

**2nd JSON variant:**

```
{
  "name": "testBookName",
  "id": 99,
  "chapters": [
    {
      "book": 99,
      "name": "testChapterName",
      "number": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Result:

`JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of "domain.Book" (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (99); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of "domain.Book" (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (99)\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 6, column: 16] (through reference chain: domain.Book[\"chapters\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->domain.Chapter[\"book\"])"`

**Book Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String author;
    private String artist;
    private String year;
    private int views;
    private double rating;

    @Lob
    private String image;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Status status;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Genre.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "genres", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private List<Genre> genres;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Chapter> chapters;

}
```

**Chapter Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Chapter {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
    private Book book;

    private int number;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Page.class, mappedBy = "chapter", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Page> pages;

}
```

**Page Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Page {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "chapter_id")
    private Chapter chapter;

    private int number;

    @Lob
    private String image;
}
```

**Controller method for POST:**

```
@PostMapping()
    public Chapter createChapter(@RequestBody Book book) {
        List<Chapter> chapters = book.getChapters();
        return chapterRepository.save(chapters.get(chapters.size() - 1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is with your **2nd JSON variant**

Change your JSON to this it will work.

```
{
 "name": "testBookName",
  "id": 99, 
  "chapters": [ 
    {
       "book": {
           "id": 99
        },
        "name": "testChapterName", 
        "number": 1
     } 
    ] 
}
```

Comment: This creates an infinity loop in json. Tried it out and this happens `*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844`. **Then this** `Failure while trying to resolve exception [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException]`.

Comment: **And finally i think the main problem** `Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: `

Comment: `Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: .domain.Book["chapters"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->domain.Chapter["book"]->domain.Book["chapters"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]`

Comment: Then add  this annotation.   `@JsonIgnoreProperties("chapters")` in your Chapter class above this field `private Book book;`